# Don't move list view position on notifydatachanged()

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm implementing endless scroll in my app. When I call the notifydatachanged event, it scroll to the top.

I'm trying to implement the endless scroll like the way Twitter did, conserving the position the user has even if they scroll to other position while the network call is requested to fetch more data.

How can I do it?

This is part of my listfragment

```
 public void getAds(String productSearch){
        isLoadingMoreAds = true;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        } else{
            setListShown(false);
        }
        Services services = Utils.getRESTAdapter();

        String state = "";
        String category = "114";

        anumexServices.getSearch( productSearch , state, category, pagination, new Callback<AdsList>() {
            @Override
            public void success(AdsList adsList, Response response) {
                try{
                    setListShown(true);
                    mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshComplete();
                    updateView(adsList.getAd());
                    isLoadingMoreAds = false;
                }catch(IllegalStateException e){
                    Log.e("Exception", "ListFragment ya no existe");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            }
        });

    }


public void updateView(List<Ad> ads){

    Boolean firstPagination = false;

    if(pagination == 0){
        adArrayList.clear();
        firstPagination = true;
    }

    if(ads.size() > 0){

        if(ads.get(ads.size() - 1).getEnd().equals("end")){
            pagination = -1;
        } else{
            pagination += 30;
        }

        adArrayList.addAll(ads);
        showBackgroundMessage(false);

    } else{
        showBackgroundMessage(true);
    }

    listAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), adArrayList);
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);

    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if(pagination>0 && !firstPagination){
        getListView().setSelectionFromTop(indexList, topList);
    }
}


//Scrolllistener
    @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        int l = visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem;
        if (l >= totalItemCount && !isLoadingMoreAds && pagination != -1 && wasSuccess) {

            /*get position of listView to set it after notifydatachanged*/

            indexList = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            View v = view.getChildAt(0);
            topList = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

            /* end */

            isLoadingMoreAds = true;

        }
    }
```

Comment: That is not supposed to happen if you do it right. But for us to know what the problem could be we need to see you code.

Comment: It's updated now with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a new `ListAdapter` every time. This will reset the the current list item to the first one. Instead only add the new items to the List and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.